# ORA-01830 - Date with time insert

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following string value:

```
15.01.2023 18.03.42
```

That I try to insert into a Date column in Oracle. This gives the dreaded ORA-01830 error however.

```
insert into my_schema.my_table (date_column) values ('15.01.2023 18.03.42')
```

Where date_column is a Date column.

When checking the NLS format for date, it returns this:

```
DD.MM.YYYY
```

The Date data type in Oracle has a hidden time element, so it should work - as I've previously selected out the time portion of the date column in this format:

```
DD.MM.YYYY HH24.MI.SS
```

So returning to the original string mentioned above, is there something missing for the Date column to accept this Date + Time string?

Comment: where is your sql code?  You need to post a [mcve]

Comment: Added the insert statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You let the DBMS guess what your string represents. Depending on session settings this may or may not work. Never leave such things to chance.

If you want to insert a fixed datetime, then use a timestamp literal:

```
insert into my_table (date_column) values (timestamp '2023-01-15 18:03:42');
```

If you are getting a string in the format 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24.mi.ss' you want to insert into a date column, then use `TO_DATE` with that explicit format:

```
insert into my_table (date_column) values (to_date(:dt, 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24.mi.ss'));
```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/LA2AWsPc

Comment: Good tip on the first snippet, but the 2nd one has been tried already. If it is of any help, the NLS_Timestamp format looks like: "DD.MM.YYYY HH24.MI.SSXFF" - does it need the "XFF"-portion defined as well?

Comment: Sorry, I was confused. To turn a string into a datetime, you need `TO_DATE` of course. I've corrected my answer accordingly and added a demo fiddle.

Comment: Never rely on session settings when writing queries. Always have your queries independent of session settings, so they are guaranteed to work properly.

Comment: Using to_date worked like a charm to insert the values, but I can't seem to retrieve the time portion when I double check if the value was retained in the date column. I'm using "select to_char(date_column, 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24.MI.SS') - and would expect the time portion to get parsed out, despite only the date displaying in the column regularly

Comment: Do you want to get the time only or the date only? Time only can be selected by TO_CHAR (date_column, 'HH24:MI:SS'), the time can be "removed" for example using TRUNC. Or TO_CHAR (date_column, 'DD.MM.YYYY')

Comment: I'm trying to get both of them, to see how the original value looks after inserting. Currently, the time portion comes out as 00.00.00 when using the to_char()- in my comment above. Expanding further, the string returned from the to_char() is: 15.01.2023 00.00.00

Comment: If you use my first insert statements, you must get the string '15.01.2023 18.03.42' with `select to_char(date_column, 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24.MI.SS') from my_table`. If you get the string '15.01.2023 00.00.00' instead, then there is problably a trigger on the table truncating the datetime. If you use the second statement and the string contains '2023-01-15 18:03:42', the same applies of course.

Comment: I see no problems, using Thorsten's fiddle (I upvoted his answer, so I think I'am allowed to do that): https://dbfiddle.uk/QjYXb2LL Could be a trigger or some strange settings in your DB.

Comment: Yeah, I will keep digging as to what's happening. Is there a reason however that inserting a pure string in the given format doesn't work, and to_date has to be used?

Comment: It works, providing the correct nls format is set, as you can see from the fiddle.

Comment: @bullfighter there is always a `to_date()`, it's just implicitly forced if you don't code it. Strings and dates are two different datatypes so type conversion is required.